# How to reference the first character of a string in Python

Tags: python, string

I am having to write a program that has someone guess a number between 1-100 and at the end when they get it right, they are asked if they want to play again and if the first letter of what they enter is a 'y' or 'Y', then it should restart the game. I am having trouble referencing the first letter of the string 'restart'

I tried to do `restart.index[0]`, `restart[0]`, `restart([0])`, `restart.index([0])`. None of these have worked for me and I cannot figure this out.

```
def main():
    game()
    restart = str(input("Do you want to play again?"))
    while restart.index([0]) == 'y' or 'Y':
        game()`
```

It will give me a type error saying `builtin_function_or_method` object is not subscriptable. If I use `restart[0]`, it will run the game again even if I do not enter a 'y' or 'Y'.

Comment: Just do `restart[0] == 'y' or restart[0] == 'Y'`

Comment: `restart.index[0].lower() == 'y'`

Answer (score 0):

A string is simply an array of characters (list), for example:

```
string = 'Hello World'
```

Can be thought of as:

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o, ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

As such if you want to access the first character (index 0) simple use:

```
string[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    game()
    restart = input("Do you want to play again?")
    while restart[0] == 'y' or restart[0] == 'Y':
        game()
```

See the second comparison. Your example was using just 'Y' and not restart[0] == 'Y', what leads to condition be always true.

Comment: I agree, but I always try to fix the error instead of improving the code. Sometimes change the whole code isn't good for the learning.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to try, this:

```py
while restart[0] == 'y' or restart[0]=='Y':
    game()
```

Or:

```py
while restart[0].lower() == 'y':
    game()
```

Answer (score 0):

These are correct, using

`while restart[0] == 'y' or restart[0]=='Y':`
  or 
`while restart[0].lower() == 'y':`

OR
`restart[0] in ('y', 'Y')` will all get the desired result.

I believe you may also run into issues where your code asks for another game only once. You can ask for a restart inside the game() function instead. eg:

`def game():
    #do game
    restart = str(input("again?"))
    if restart[0].lower() == 'y' :
        game()`

That way the question will be asked each time, and you will have a fresh variable